# What would be a good key for some composite object?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I am making this simple class:

```
@interface BGPairButtonCatalog : NSObject

@property (readonly,nonatomic) UIButton * btnButton;
@property (readonly,nonatomic) BGReviewsTablesatProfile * rtpReviewsTables;

-(id)initWithBtn:(UIButton*) btnButton andReviewsTablesatProfile: (BGReviewsTablesatProfile *) rtpReviewsTables;
@end
```

Now, I want an NSDictionary object of that class.

The NSDictionary must be search able through btnButton.

However, btnButton is not a good key for NSDictionary.

So maybe an element of btnButton. What? Address?

Comment: You can go the simple route and use a simple string to represent the button.  Just name the string in such a manner that describes the context of the button. Or, add a property to the class which can be an integer an then assign a unique value to it, and store/search in array instead of dictionary.

Comment: how do I get the address of the button as string?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already using the `tag` property of `btnButton`, I would suggest generating a unique integer (use a counter and a generator method, for instance) and assign it to each button. Then simply index the `NSDictionary` on an `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` of the button's tag.

You can look up the resultant catalog object like so:

```
BGPairButtonCatalog *catalog = (BGPairButtonCatalog *)self.btnIndex[@(keyButton.tag)];
```